# What does the SERVER do?

Tags: server

I'm pretty new to programming and I study by myself, and it's not even my major. It doesn't matter because I wanted to learn how to make an app.
I know I don't know much and I don't get the concept of the back-end. That's why I need you guys help.

I just don't get what the SERVER does, its ROLE. It is a very absurd question but its because I really don't get it.

I tried to learn JSP. It's literally making a Server Page right? And when client sends a page with a query, the server replies, as the developer made the server page.

I understood this procedure. However, I still don't get the server. For example, linux server, microsoft server, and AWS Server Settings, Server Management... these kinds of Servers.

Any simple help even one sentence will help me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is too broad... Getting a JSP book or tutorial or a video would help build concepts

Comment: I've went through two tutorials about JSP. I still don't get it. :( 
I don't understand why it is even broad... Are there many types of servers?

Answer (score 1):

You got it right. `Client requests, Server responds` 
 
There are specific servers for specific needs of the clients:

- **Hotels** act as servers by providing rooms to customers (or clients).
- **Server Platforms** or Operating Systems (like Windows, Linux) respond to our actions. For example, they serve file content from computer memory, if we double click on a text file.
- **Web Servers** respond with web pages (made using HTML, JSP etc.) when the client requests for it (GET https://www.stackoverflow.com)
- **FTP Servers** respond with files requested by the client. FileZilla is a good implementation.

Servers might need more resources to handle these requests. For example, AWS provides resources like computing power, database storage for web applications etc.